# Access AMD compiled TypeScript from external JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd

I have compiled some TypeScript from a single Engine.ts file, which I could easily access from JavaScript afterwards.

Engine.ts

```
class BaseObject {

}

class ExtendedObject extends BaseObject {

    public static DoStuff ()
    {

    }
}
```

I compile using

```
tsc --module amd --outfile dist/engine.js
```

In my JavaScript, I can call ExtendedObject.DoStuff(), and it works!

However, as my project will grow I'd like to separate my .ts files. After separating, I get some errors in my .ts files and I have to add some exports & imports.

BaseObject.ts

```
export class BaseObject {

}
```

ExtendedObject.ts

```
import {BaseObject} from "./BaseObject";

export class ExtendedObject extends BaseObject {

    public static DoStuff ()
    {

    }
}
```

I compile using the same command, which groups them together in a single engine.js file. However, now I can no longer access my method in the same way, I get 'ExtendedObject' is not defined... The compiled JavaScript also looks quite a bit more convoluted:

```
define("Engine/BaseObject", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    exports.BaseObject = void 0;
    class BaseObject {
    }
    exports.BaseObject = BaseObject;
});
```

I'm quite new to web development and this has me stumped. I can keep working in the same file but that's going to be a big issue at some point. I can manually create a 'combine all files and remove imports/exports' script, but that seems... messy.

I hope I'm just missing something obvious. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I had to change my tsconfig.json from:

```
"include": [
    "./src/*"
  ]
```

to

```
"include": [
    "src/*.ts",
    "./src/Engine/*.ts"
  ]
```

Then I was able to remove all import/export statements from my .ts files and the export was the same as if it were a single file.

The Engine sub-folder was needed because I had organized some files there - it's also possible to use

```
"./src/*/*.ts"
```

to include all sub-folders